# How to auto fill Unpaid Leave of Worked days to 0(Zero) in Employee Payslip?

Tags: odoo, default, odoo-8, autofill

In the current payroll,while selecting the employee name, Normal working days and Unpaid Leave will fill automatically if the employee has taken the unpaid leave in current month under Worked days.By default i want to auto fill Unpaid Leave number of days and number of hours(Only Unpaid Leave) to 0(Zero) if the employee does not taken Unpaid Leave for that particular month.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use context for this, for example fill default value for `my_field` will be `context = {'default_my_field': 0}`, also you can use `my_field = fields.Integer(string="My Field", default=0)` here you can use function as value for default attribute.